# How to keep connection alive between two process

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I try to keep the connection between the two consoles alive even after a connection has been made between them. I use Microsoft libraries- Pipe.
Once the Server and the Client are connected they are automatically disconnected.

[image]

Is it possible to keep the connection alive for a few minutes?
My goal is to transfer information between the client and the server and return the information after changes have been made by the server.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client

Comment: What does "Once the Server and the Client connected they are automatically disconnected" mean?

Comment: I added the image @SamVarshavchik

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Additionally, showing the output of unknown code doesn't really mean much. All shown code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, as a [mre], please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: You keep a connection alive by not closing it. Programming works best if you understand the code you are entering into your code editor.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft's sample code for a named pipe server (for which you provided the link), the server simply calls `ReadFile` once to obtain a message, then processes the message and generates a response text using `GetAnswerToRequest`, and then sends that response using `WriteFile`. Afterwards, it gracefully closes the pipe by calling:

```
FlushFileBuffers(hPipe); 
DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe); 
CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

When the client has finished reading the reply message from the server, it is programmed to print the following line and to exit afterwards:

```
printf("\n<End of message, press ENTER to terminate connection and exit>");
```

In your question, you wrote the following:

> Once the Server and the Client connected they are automatically disconnected.

This statement is not quite correct. As stated above, the client is programmed to exit as soon as it has finished receiving the reply from the server.

If you want to keep the connection alive for a longer period, then you can for example

1. reprogram the server to delay the sending of the response to the client, or
2. reprogram the server to process more than one message per client before closing the pipe, and reprogram the client to read more than one message from the pipe before exiting.